# phpword addText() align justify

Tags: phpword

When I use `addText()` it works fine with `align=center`, left or right, but when I try use `align=justify` script works without problems, but when I try to open `.docx` file it gives me error and file is not openning.

It would be appreciated if someone knows solution.

```
$text = "some text";
$PHPWord->addFontStyle('r2Style', array('bold'=>false, 'italic'=>false, 'size'=>12));
$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('p2Style', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
$section->addText($text, 'r2Style', 'p2Style');
```

Comment: Which phpword version are you using? The above paragraph style with 'align' => 'justify' seemed to work just fine (storing & opening the result in Word & LibreOffice) with phpword 0.12.0.

Comment: I use same 0.12.0 version, apache and php on windows.

Answer (score 11):

try change `'align'=>'left'` to `'align'=>'both'`

```
$text = "some text";
$PHPWord->addFontStyle('r2Style', array('bold'=>false, 'italic'=>false, 'size'=>12));
$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('p2Style', array('align'=>'both', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
$section->addText($text, 'r2Style', 'p2Style');
```

Answer (score 5):

in src\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc.php you will find the list of valid alignment options. "justify" is not (and has not been as far as I can tell) a valid option.

```
const START = 'start';
const CENTER = 'center';
const END = 'end';
const BOTH = 'both';
const MEDIUM_KASHIDA = 'mediumKashida';
const DISTRIBUTE = 'distribute';
const NUM_TAB = 'numTab';
const HIGH_KASHIDA = 'highKashida';
const LOW_KASHIDA = 'lowKashida';
const THAI_DISTRIBUTE = 'thaiDistribute';
```

"distribute" is close, but the last line will be spread across the width of the paragraph even if it is a single word. I have had success with "thaiDistribute" and "lowKashida" as values for the "align" property. Both give a decent "Justify" as you would expect in Word.